# Supabase getBucket function is giving a 404 error

Tags: supabase, supabase-js

I am trying to follow supabase's documentation at "https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-getbucket" to retrieve bucket details. When I write the following code, I get a 404 error;

```
  const { data, error } = await supabase
  .storage
  .getBucket('product-images')
  console.log(data, error)
```

Data returns null and error returns 404 bucket is not found.
Bucket is public and have permissions.
Not sure what else to check?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user calling `getBucket` has the permission to access the bucket.

https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/security/access-control